# How to combine bitstreams (thrid party IP cores) to use it in main design?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog

In FPGA design when we buy Intellectual property (IP) from a vendor I assume they provide the IP core in a form of bitstream file.
My question is how IP core integrated with Xilinx / Altera's SOC development products?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assume that they are provided as bitstream files? Bitstream files are the fully fitted design files used to program a specific FPGA and hardware, they are not used for IP cores.

What you will receive is most likely an encrypted HDL netlist with a black-box instantiation file - a Verilog or VHDL template module that shows you how to instantiate their design.

Alternatively you might get a set of encrypted HDL files and a license key to allow the specific synthesis tool to decrypt them and compile without you ever seeing the HDL they contain.

You won't receive a fully fitted design because there is no way they can know what specific device you are using, and no way for you to integrate that into your own design.

In any case the supplier will tell you what they are supplying and how to use it, so really this answer (and the question) are just speculation.